# If select option is not :disabled then removeClass

Tags: jquery

Trying to achieve this:

```
var selectedOption = $("select option");

if(selectedOption.is(":disabled")){
   $('#opacity').addClass('opacity');
} else if(selectedOption.is(":enabled")){
   console.log("not"); // looking to removeClass('opacity');
}
```

my HTML

```
<select name="url" id="listUpdate">
  <option selected="" disabled="" value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="http://www.ulr1.ee">ulr1</option>
  <option value="http://www.url2.ee">ulr1</option>
  <option value="www.url3.ee">ulr1</option>
</select>
```

The class opacity gets added nicely, although I am not able to remove it with :enabled when the option changes from the :disabled option. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i can see the comments you can make use of `.toggleClass()` method by passing class name as first parameter and second one as a conditional check:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $('#opacity').toggleClass('opacity', $(":selected", this).is(':disabled'));
}).change();
```

```css
button {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
.opacity{opacity:0.2;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="url" id="listUpdate">
  <option selected="" disabled="" value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="http://www.ulr1.ee">ulr1</option>
  <option value="http://www.url2.ee">ulr1</option>
  <option value="www.url3.ee">ulr1</option>
</select>

<button id='opacity'>Opacity</button>
```

Comment: suited better with my needs and is cleaner. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a simple change:

```
var selectedOption = $("select option:selected");
```

Or use this:

```
} else if (!selectedOption.is(":disabled")) {
```

And finally, make sure you are binding this function to the `.change()` event of `select` and not just to `document`'s ready function:

```
$(function () {
  $(select).change(function () {
    if(selectedOption.is(":disabled")){
       $('#opacity').addClass('opacity');
    } else if(selectedOption.is(":enabled")){
       console.log("not"); // looking to removeClass('opacity');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately can't getting working. Can you post a fiddle? I tried it but still no change when I change the select

Comment: The `select` should be replaced with the right selector.

Comment: sorry, was using the wrong selector by typo. Thanks a bunch!